Search Data using jquery from HTML table
I am trying to write an application using python and i am trying to fetch data from mysql DB. After fetching data i want to add a ajax search query to filter the users. when I open the html file without data Jquery is working very find. But when i fetch the data jquery is not working. Here is my code for HTML and Python.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>CRM Users</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            font-family: TimesNewRoman;
            font-size: 9px;
                    }
    </style>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Document ready");

    // Initial search functionality
    function applySearch() {
        var searchValue = $("#searchInput").val().toUpperCase();

        $("#userTable tbody tr").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).find("td:first").text().toUpperCase();

            if (id.includes(searchValue)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }

    // Apply search on keyup
    $("#searchInput").on("keyup", applySearch);

    // Reapply search after data load
    function reloadData() {
        // Assuming you're loading data using AJAX, you can reapply the search after the data is loaded
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin_dashboard",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                // Update the table with new data
                // For example: $("#userTable tbody").html(response);

                // Reapply the search
                applySearch();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error("Error loading data:", error);
            }
        });
    }

    // Call reloadData function when needed
    // reloadData();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<br></br>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="search" placeholder="Search by Username">
</div>

<div class="mx-auto">
<table border="0" class="table table-hover mt-0" id="userTable">
    <thead style="font-size: 12px">
    <tr class="table table-hover">
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">ID</th>
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">Username</th>
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">is Admin</th>
        <th class="table-primary" scope="col">Email</th>
        <!-- Add other table headers as needed -->
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-group-divider" style="font-size: 9px">
    {% for user in crm_users %}
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <td class="table-primary">{{ user[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[5] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[6] }}</td>
        <!-- Add other table data fields as needed -->
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>



Any help in this is greatly appreciated.
